# javascript function help to get the Element by ID from a Frame's src?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

`Default.aspx`

```
<html>
    <frameset id="MainFrameset" rows="78,*" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0">
        <frame application="yes" name="menuFrame" src="<% = GetMenuFrameSrcUrl() %>" scrolling="no" noresize>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

`Default.aspx.cs`

```
public string GetMenuFrameSrcUrl()
{
    return "http://localhost/Application1/Pages/MenuPage.aspx"
}
```

`MenuPage.aspx`

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="customControl" TagName="Menu" Src="/Controls/Menu.ascx" %>
<html>
    <body bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" rightmargin="0">
        <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
            <customControl:menu id="Menu1" runat="server">
            </customControl:menu>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`AnotherPage.aspx`

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testFunction(args, name) {

            //Need help here...How can I get the reference of Menu1 id?

            //I can get this:
            alert(top.frames[0].name);      //menuFrame
            //But don't know how I can take it further to get some Element ID from the MenuPage.aspx which is the source of this Frame???
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Question: How can I get the reference of Menu1 id from testFunction?

Thanks,

Voodoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame document trick is thus:

```
var frm = top.frames[0];
var doc = frm.contentDocument || frm.Document;  // Document (capitalized) in IE, contentDocument otherwise
var menu = doc.getElementById("Menu1");
```

But, if Menu1 has a different ClientID, you might try this route:

```
MenuPage.aspx

<script type="text/javascript">
function getMenu() {
    return document.getElementByID("<%=Menu1.ClientID%>");
}
</script>

AnotherPage.aspx

var menu = top.frames[0].getMenu();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a snippet of ASP.NET server code to accomplish this.  Note this assumes that your javascipt function is contained in the  tag of Default.aspx (the same page as the frames).

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testFunction(args, name) {

            var menu1 = document.getElementById('<%=Menu1.ClientID %>');
            //note I've never done this with framesets, so it might be
            top.frames[0].document.getElementById('<%=Menu1.ClientID %>');
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: The assumption that this function is in Default.aspx is not right. The function has to be in another page, specifically `AnotherPage.aspx`